# Issue Connecting to AutoCAD LT 2024: Seeking Assistance with Python Code

Tags: python, pywin32, autocad, comtypes, autocad-scripts

Hello StackOverflow community,
I am currently facing a challenge with connecting or opening AutoCAD LT 2024 using a Python script. Below is the relevant code snippet that I am using for this purpose:

```py
try:
    app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
    logging.info('AutoCAD Already Open..!!!')
except:
    app = comtypes.client.CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")
    logging.info('AutoCAD Opening..!!!')
```

Unfortunately, I am encountering the following error:
`pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)`

I suspect there might be an issue with the registration of the AutoCAD class. I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or updates to the code that could help resolve this issue. If you have encountered a similar problem or have expertise in working with AutoCAD LT 2024 and Python, your guidance would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

i am checking with comtypes.client or pywin32 library

Comment: AFAIK AutoCAD LT does not expose a COM interface for third party apps.

Comment: Expanding on @LeeMac's comment, [the documentation](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACDLT/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-E6429154-36DF-4D84-8ABC-9FCA15B66158) says that the LT version has very limited API support.

Comment: It looks like Autocad LT doesn't register their COM library intentionally, but `comtypes` allows loading custom COM interfaces from `.dll` file from file system. So it doesn't require a registration in Windows Registry. Example: `UIA_dll = comtypes.client.GetModule('UIAutomationCore.dll'); ui_automation_client = comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient;`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't download even trial version of Autocad LT in my country. So I'm unable to double check which `.dll` file contains some COM interfaces.